# How i use ajax with wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to ajax.  I want to place a combobox on page. Combobox contain option
by popularity, by price and by date.

I want to change the content of div with ajax without reloading the page.

e.g i am displaying a product of watches. when user change the value at combo box, the value/images displayed at page will be change as accordingly.

1) i want to know how to use ajax with word press.
2)code to achieve this.

I am using this code:

```
            <div class="prodimg">


<ul class="rcollpro">

    <?php
        $ordr ='date';
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',  'product_cat' => 'Rings', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'orderby' =>'$ordr','order' => 'DESC' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                <li class="rcollproli">    

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?></a>

                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                           <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span><br />



                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>
                </li><!-- /span3 -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</ul><!-- /row-fluid -->

            </div>
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've already tried? Did you read the WP Codex content about AJAX in WP? http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins (Title says "plugins", but should work fine for themes too.)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: actually what i want to achieve is that i want to change result of page (image display on page from wp db) Product image will change on selection of option from combo box. If user select option sort by popular the page content load as per option.

Answer (score 1):

You dont actually need to implement Ajax, but you can do it with simple JS. I can share a simple code with you for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function hourChange(selectObj) {
   var selectIndex=selectObj.selectedIndex;
   var selectValue=selectObj.options[selectIndex].text;
   var output=document.getElementById("output");
   //alert(output.innerText);
   output.innerHTML=selectValue;
 }

</script>

<select id="hour" onchange="hourChange(this);">

  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>

</select>

<p/>

you selected: <span id="output">1</span>
```

Try this in simple HTML file. And it's easy to implement it in WP too.

Comment: <form action="" class="woocommerce-ordering"> 
<select name="orderby" class="orderby" onchange="showproduct(this.value)">
<option value="menu_order">Default sorting</option>
<option value="popularity">Sort by popularity</option>
<option value="date ">Sort by newness</option>
<option value="price">Sort by price: low to high</option>
<option value="price-desc">Sort by price: high to low</option>
</select>
</form>

Comment: http://www.fossil.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryView?catalogId=25005&parent_category_rn=357584&categoryId=341111&langId=-1&departmentCategoryId=331209&storeId=12052&ddkey=http:ResolveCategoryIdentifier#builder

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution below for your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#selector").change(function() {
   var selectedValue = $("#selector option:selected").val();
   alert('Selected text ' + selectedValue);
});});
</script>
</head>

    <body>
<select name="orderby" class="orderby" id="selector"> 
<option value="menu_order">Default sorting</option> 
<option value="popularity">Sort by popularity</option> 
<option value="date ">Sort by newness</option> 
<option value="price">Sort by price: low to high</option> 
<option value="price-desc">Sort by price: high to low</option> 
</select> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is showing me selected option. what i want is that "data from wp db will be extracted and displayed as per option selected" As in my code you can see a loop is running to display data from db.

Comment: i want to change values in ul in code                           $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',  'product_cat' => 'Rings', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'orderby' =>'$ordr','order' => 'DESC' );